# Remove imeoption from editText android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, imeoptions

I am having 4 `EditText`s in my layout. I want to apply `imeOptions` for the `EditText`s as below,

- editTest1: ACTION_NEXT
- editTest2: ACTION_NEXT
- editTest3: ACTION_NONE with disabled mode
- editTest4: ACTION_DONE

So when user clicks the next from the 2nd `EditText`, It should directly go to the 4th `EditText`.

But when i try this, it is not working. Please guide me to achieve this.

Comment: post your XMl code...

Comment: "But when i try this, it is not working." Can you post some code so we can tell what's wrong instead of writing it all for you?

Comment: Isn't nextFocusDown used for this purpose?

Comment: editTest1.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
editTest2.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
editTest3.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE);
editTest4.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

This is what the code i tried yet...